# XCode TableViewCell to URL

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5

I've got a Table View Controller which has about 6 static cells, all of which I wish to point to separate external URLs. Should be straightforward enough but I can't seem to figure out how to do it. I'm using the storyboard at the moment and haven't created any custom classes for the table view yet.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: do you want when a cell to go to a url when clicked or do you want cell to show different html content?

Comment: You're going to really have to elaborate on your question. General info should be found on tutorials and in documentation etc.

Comment: Ideally I'd like it to go to a page in Safari using a similar method to this: `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well. Create a custom UIViewController class. Then go to the storyboard and select your new UIViewController class as the 'custom class'.

Right click drag from your static table view to the file owner and select delegate, in order to receive the taps on your cells.

Then implement the

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

method. For instance like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   if(indexPath.row==0)
   {
      [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];
   }else if(indexPath.row==1)
      [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.bing.com"]];
   }
}
```

This would be the fastest way..

Comment: My UITableView is embedded within a container, will that make a difference?

Comment: I gave that a shot and no dice. I can't seem to get prepopulated tablecells to point to URLs. Any advice?

Comment: What do you mean by container? If its a viewControllerContainer then you of course put the code I showed you into the contained viewControllres code.. If its just inside a view, it does not make a difference. Did you set the delegate?